# Tkinter Async Error...without multithreading?

Tags: python, timer, tkinter

I've recently needed to do some GUI work with Python and stumbled on Tkinter. For the most part, I like it; it's clean and mostly intuitive and brief. There is, however, one little sticking point for me: sometimes it crashes out of nowhere. The program will run normally five times in a row and then the sixth time, halfway through it will freeze and I will get the error

```
Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread
```

My efforts to find a solution to this problem, both on this website and others, all have to do with multithreading, but I don't use multiple threads. Not explicitly, anyway. I suspect the fact that I have a timer in the GUI is to blame, but I have not been able to figure out why the error pops up, or indeed why it is so infrequent.

What follows is the shortest tkinter program I've written. This happens in all of them, so I suspect the problem will be easiest to see here. Any and all help is appreciated, just don't point me toward another solution without telling me how it applies to my code, because I assure you, I have looked at it, and it either doesn't apply or I didn't understand how it did. I don't mind having missed the answer, but I'm new to tkinter (and to multithreading in general) so I might need it told more explicitly.

This code is for a simulation of a game show I saw online. Most of it can probably be safely ignored, but I'm pasting it all here because I don't know where the error is from.

```
import re
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, DISABLED, Button, Label, font, NORMAL, ttk
from random import choice
import winsound

class Question:
    def __init__(self, t, a, o):
        self.text = t.strip().capitalize() + "?"
        self.answer = a.strip().title()
        self.options = o
        self.firstIsRight = self.answer.lower() == self.options[0].lower()
        assert self.firstIsRight or self.answer.lower() == self.options[1].lower(), self

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.text == other.text

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{1} or {2}, {0}".format(self.text, self.options[0], self.options[1])

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.setup()
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.customFont = font.Font(family="Times New Roman", size=30)
        self.createWidgets()

    def setup(self):
        self.questions = []
        with open("twentyone.txt",'r') as file:
            for line in file:
                groups = re.split("[,\.\?]",line)
                answers = re.split(" or ",groups[0])
                self.questions.append(Question(groups[1], groups[2], answers))

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.gamePanel = Frame(self)
        self.gamePanel.grid(column=0,row=0)
        self.displayPanel = Frame(self)
        self.displayPanel.grid(column=0,row=1)
        self.buttonPanel = Frame(self)
        self.buttonPanel.grid(column=0,row=2)

        self.QUIT = Button(self.buttonPanel,text="QUIT",font=self.customFont,command=self.quit)
        self.QUIT.grid(row=0,column=2)

        self.BEGIN = Button(self.buttonPanel, text="BEGIN",font=self.customFont, command = self.begin)
        self.BEGIN.grid(row=0,column=0)

        self.STOP = Button(self.buttonPanel, text="STOP",font=self.customFont, command = self.stop)
        self.STOP.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.STOP["state"] = DISABLED

        self.TITLE = Label(self.gamePanel,text="21 Questions Wrong",font=self.customFont,bg="Black",fg="White")
        self.TITLE.grid(columnspan=2)
        self.questionText = Label(self.gamePanel,text="Questions go here",font=self.customFont,wraplength=400)
        self.questionText.grid(row=1,columnspan=2)
        self.leftChoice = Button(self.gamePanel,text="Option 1",font=self.customFont)
        self.leftChoice.grid(row=2,column=0)
        self.rightChoice = Button(self.gamePanel,text="Option 2",font=self.customFont)
        self.rightChoice.grid(row=2,column=1)

        self.timerText = Label(self.displayPanel, text="150",font=self.customFont)
        self.timerText.grid(row=0)
        self.progress = ttk.Progressbar(self.displayPanel, length=100,maximum=22)
        self.progress.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10)

    def begin(self):       
        self.timer(250)
        self.asked = []
        self.STOP["state"] = NORMAL
        self.leftChoice["state"] = NORMAL
        self.rightChoice["state"] = NORMAL
        self.restart = False
        self.askNewQuestion()

    def askNewQuestion(self):   
        if self.restart:
            self.currentQuestion = self.asked[int(self.progress["value"])]
        else:
            self.currentQuestion = choice([i for i in self.questions if i not in self.asked])
            self.asked.append(self.currentQuestion)
        self.questionDisplay()

    def questionDisplay(self):
        self.questionText["text"] = self.currentQuestion.text
        self.leftChoice["text"] = self.currentQuestion.options[0]
        self.rightChoice["text"] = self.currentQuestion.options[1]
        if self.currentQuestion.firstIsRight:
            self.leftChoice["command"] = self.correct 
            self.rightChoice["command"] = self.wrong
        else:
            self.leftChoice["command"] = self.wrong
            self.rightChoice["command"] = self.correct

    def correct(self):
        self.progress.step()
        if self.progress["value"] >= 21:
            self.gameOver(True, 21)
        else:
            if self.progress["value"] >= len(self.asked):
                self.restart = False
            self.askNewQuestion()

    def wrong(self):
        self.restart = True
        self.progress["value"] = 0
        winsound.Beep(750,700)
        self.askNewQuestion()

    def stop(self):
        self.after_cancel(self.timerAfter)
        self.BEGIN["state"] = NORMAL
        self.STOP["state"] = DISABLED

    def gameOver(self, success, longest):
        self.after_cancel(self.timerAfter)
        self.BEGIN["state"] = NORMAL
        self.STOP["state"] = DISABLED
        self.questionText["text"] = "Congratulations!" if success else "Too Bad!"
        self.leftChoice["text"] = "Game"
        self.leftChoice["state"] = DISABLED
        self.rightChoice["text"] = "Over"
        self.rightChoice["state"] = DISABLED
        self.showPoints(success, longest)

    def showPoints(self, s, l):
        if s:
            timeTaken = max(0, 100-int(self.timerText["text"]))
            print("You scored {0} points".format(1000-10*timeTaken))
        else:
            print("You scored no points")

    def timer(self, time):
        self.BEGIN["state"] = DISABLED
        self.STOP["state"] = NORMAL
        self.runTimer(time)

    def runTimer(self, current=None, resume=False):
        if current is not None:
            self.current = current

        self.timerText["text"] = self.current

        if self.current == 0:
            self.gameOver(False, len(self.asked)-1)
        else:
            self.current -= 1
            self.timerAfter = self.after(1000,self.runTimer)


root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.master.title("Score Calculator!")
app.anchor("center")
root.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

Comment: Can you edit your code down to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we don't have to dig through all the irrelevant parts?

Comment: winsound probably uses threading so it can play longer sounds while the rest of the program continues onwards, but I don't see why that would make Tkinter unhappy.

Comment: If you remove the use of winsound, does the problem go away?

Comment: @Kevin and Bryan, winsound is not the issue. The other programs I wrote with tkinter do not use it and experience the same problem. I also tried removing it from this one, but that did not fix the issue.

Comment: groups = re.split("[,\.\?]",line)  --> You may have a newline on the last line of the file, or a blank line, etc. so this returns nothing. Add some print statements so you know how far it gets.

Comment: But your problem is possibly here "self.gamePanel = Frame(self)", i.e. should be Frame(master)??.  I would suggest that removing inheriting the Frame class, would mean that all widgets would be created in the same thread, and so the problem would go away, but this is something you will have to test, so add print statements to see if createWidgets() executes completely.

Comment: I tried your suggestion @CurlyJoe, and it seemed to work. I don't know why the place I copied the code from had it inherited but it seems to work fine inheriting from master and I haven't had it crash since. Thanks!